# Perl threaded server not working as expected

Tags: multithreading, perl, sockets

Need help regarding this threaded Perl code. Here I am trying to create a server inside a thread. This server code is receiving and sending the messages as expected, but it is working only sometimes. Sometimes it is not receiving and sending the messages.

here is the server code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use experimentals;
use threads;

sub main() {
    async {
        use IO::Socket qw(AF_INET SOCK_STREAM SHUT_WR);
        my $server = IO::Socket->new(
            Domain => AF_INET,
            Type => SOCK_STREAM,
            Proto => 'tcp',
            LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
            LocalPort => 8447,
            ReusePort => 1,
            Listen => 10,
        ) or say "cannot create socket";

        say "listening on 8447";

        while(1) {
            my $client = $server->accept();
            my $clientAddress = $client->peerhost();
            my $clientPort = $client->peerport();
            say "Connection from $clientAddress: $clientPort";

            my $data = "";
            $client->recv($data, 1024);
            say "recieved data: ", $data, "\n";

            $data = "Thread id: " . threads->self->tid();
            $client->send($data);
            $client->close();
        }

        $server->close();
    };
}

my $monitorThread = async { 
    while(1) {
        foreach my $thread (threads->list(threads::joinable)) {
            $thread->detach();
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
};

main();

while(1) {
    my @threads = threads->list(threads::all);
    if(scalar @threads == 1) {
        $monitorThread->detach();
        last;
    } else {
        sleep(1);
    }
}

exit();
```

here is the client code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use experimentals;
use IO::Socket qw(AF_INET SOCK_STREAM SHUT_WR);

my $client = IO::Socket->new(
    Domain => AF_INET,
    Type => SOCK_STREAM,
    Proto => 'tcp',
    PeerPort => 8447,
    PeerHost => '0.0.0.0',
) or say "Cannot create socket: ", $IO::Socket::errstr;

my $size = $client->send("Hello World!");
say "Sent data of length: ", $size;

my $buffer;
$client->recv($buffer, 1024);
say "Got back: ", $buffer;

$client->close();
```

Please, help me in writing the proper server code inside the thread.

Edit section:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use experimentals;
use threads;

$| = 1;

sub clientConnection($client) {
    async {
        my $clientAddress = $client->peerhost();
        my $clientPort = $client->peerport();
        say "Connection from $clientAddress: $clientPort";

        my $data = "";
        $client->recv($data, 1024);
        say "recieved data: ", $data, "\n";

        my $tid = "Thread id: " . threads->self->tid();
        $client->send($tid);
        $client->close();
    };
}

sub main() {
    async {
        use IO::Socket;
        my $server = IO::Socket->new(
            Domain => IO::Socket::AF_INET,
            Type => IO::Socket::SOCK_STREAM,
            Proto => 'tcp',
            LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
            LocalPort => 8449,
            ReusePort => 1,
            Listen => 10,
        ) or say "cannot create socket";

        say "listening on 8449";

        while(1) {
            my $client = $server->accept();
            clientConnection($client);
        }

        $server->close();
    };
}

my $signalThread = async {
    use sigtrap 'handler' => \&signalHandler, qw(INT);
};
sub signalHandler($signalName) {
    say "got an intterupt, print some info";
    my @threads = threads->list(threads::all);
    say "remaining threads: ", scalar @threads;
}

my $monitorThread = async { 
    while(1) {
        foreach my $thread (threads->list(threads::joinable)) {
            $thread->detach();
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
};

main();

while(1) {
    my @threads = threads->list(threads::all);
    if(scalar @threads == 1) {
        $monitorThread->detach();
        last;
    } else {
        sleep(1);
    }
}

exit();
```

Edit using Socket module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use experimentals;
use threads;

sub clientConnection($client, $newSocket) {
    async {
        my ($clientPort, $clientAddr) = unpack_sockaddr_in($client);
        my $tid = threads->self->tid();
        print $newSocket "a message from server $tid";
        print "Connection recieved from ", inet_ntoa($clientAddr),
                        ": ", $clientPort , "\n";
        close $newSocket;
    };
}

sub main() {
    async {
        use Socket;

        my $port = 8459;
        my $proto = getprotobyname('tcp');
        my $server = "localhost";

        socket(SOCKET, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto) 
                    or say "cannot open socket $!";
        setsockopt(SOCKET, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
                    or say "cannot set socket option to SO_REUSEADDR $!";

        bind(SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in($port, inet_aton($server)))
                    or say "Cannot bind to port ", $port;
        
        listen(SOCKET, 5) or say "listen Error: $!";
        say "Server started on port ", $port;

        my $newSocket;
        while(my $client = accept($newSocket, SOCKET)) {
            clientConnection($client, $newSocket);
        }
    };
}

my $signalThread = async {
    use sigtrap 'handler' => \&signalHandler, qw(INT);
};
sub signalHandler($signalName) {
    say "got an intterupt, print some info";
    my @threads = threads->list(threads::all);
    say "remaining threads: ", scalar @threads;
}

my $monitorThread = async { 
    while(1) {
        foreach my $thread (threads->list(threads::joinable)) {
            $thread->detach();
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
};

main();

while(1) {
    my @threads = threads->list(threads::all);
    if(scalar @threads == 1) {
        $monitorThread->detach();
        last;
    } else {
        sleep(1);
    }
}

exit();
```

Comment: I changed the port number, the code is working properly. I'm deleting this question.

Comment: Can i write code like in the edit section.

Comment: " Sometimes it is not receiving and sending the messages" is too vague of a description. Provides specifics!

Comment: the client is not sending and recieving the messages. sometimes partially. then i implemented the server code using plain Socket module, it worked fine. when I changed the port number it worked properly using IO::Socket module also.

 try copying the code and run it, and explain me why such a thing happend on that particular port 8447. the server is running fine on other ports. 

can i write async in clientConnection() function is it useful. 

what is the purpose of listen in creating the socket.

direct me to more documentation of using Socket module for ipv6 connections.

Comment: Not sending or not receiving? What does it do instead? What error does it return? etc. Like I said, you need to provide specifics.

Comment: Re "*when I changed the port number it worked properly*", This suggests one of two problems: 1) You tried to bind to a port that requires root (such as the ports below 1024 on some systems). 2) You tried to bind to a port that was already bound (for example, because you already had a copy of the program running). /// Either way, `bind` will tell you why it failed.